# If $P$ is a group $|P| = p^\alpha$ for some $p$, then it has a nontrivial center

Tags: abstract-algebra

So i was reading this statement from Dummit Foote and the entire idea lies in the class equation

> [image]

$$|P| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i = 1}^r [P: C_P(g_i) ]$$

Now what I don't understand is that what if $\alpha = 1$?

When $|P| = p$, this should mean that the centralizer $C_P(g_i) = \{ x \in P: xg_ix^{-1} = g_i\}$ is either the whole group or $\{ e\}$. If it is the whole group does that mean $P = Z(G) = C_P(g_i)?$ Since $[P : C_P(g_i) ] = 1$, so doesn't the class equation say $|Z(G)| = 0$?

What about the rest of the $g_is$? And if it is $\{e \}$  Doesn't that mean there exists an element that does not commute with anything?

Comment: If G is a group of prime order, p, every nonidentity element must have order p, so the group is cyclic, hence it's abelian.

Comment: @BillTrok That is a good point, but what the mistake in my reasoning with regards to the class equation though?

Comment: If $\lvert P\rvert=p$, then $r=0$ because the sum is over representatives of non-central conjugacy classes.

Comment: The centralizer is $P$ for every element in an Abelian group $P$; the sum in the equation, however, is specifically indexed on representatives of the $non$-central conjugacy classes, i.e. elements that do not have $C_P(g) = P$. This is not true for any element in an abelian group $P$, so the sum is empty.

Comment: @Gae.S. but this is a priori knowing that $G$ is cyclic right? If we don't know that yet, how do we deduce the sum is empty?

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. The formula is a formula. It requires no a priori knowledge. You can prove it for any group. The fact that $r=0$ is true when $|P|=p,$ whether you know it or not. @Hawk

Comment: @hawk By definition, every $g_i$ is an element such that $C_P(g_i)\ne P$. Therefore $[P:C_P(g_i)]\ne 1$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews My point is that if we do not use the fact that $|G| = p$ implies it is cyclic (and hence abelian) and just work from the class equation like I wrote, how do we deduce $G = Z(G)$

Comment: @Gae.S. so we about the case $C_P(g_i) = \{e \}$ for some $i$?

Comment: @Hawk In that case $[P:C_P(g_i)]=\lvert P\rvert$ and $p$ divides it, as advertised.

Comment: But from the class equation $|P| = |Z(P)| + \sum |P|$, doesn't this mean $|Z(G)| = 0$ possibly or $|Z(G)| = 1$?

Comment: Yes, the formula gives that either $g\in Z(P)$ or $[P:C_p(g)]=p.$ Since $|Z(P)|=p$ or $|Z(P)|=1,$ if any $g_i\not\in Z(P)$ then you'd have $|Z(P)|=1$ and the formula would imply $p=1+\sum_{i} p$ which is impossible.

Comment: @hawk No: "which means that either $\lvert Z(P)\rvert=0$ or $\sum_{i=1}^r [P:C_P(g_i)]=0$." (by the fact that either $r=0$ or the sum is greater or equal to $\lvert P\rvert$). And since $\lvert Z(G)\rvert\ge 1$ for all $G$, this leaves little choice.

Comment: Sorry for being slow, I am looking at this purely from an analysis view and so far all of your answers actually answered the original question, but in the class equation, what does it mean when some summands in $\sum_{i = 1}^r$ have $[P: C_P(g_i)] = p$ but others are forced to be $0$?

Answer (score 1):

If $|P|=p$ and $r>0$ then there is some $g\in P$ with $g\not\in Z(P).$ Thus $Z(P)=\{e\},$ since the only subgroups of $P$ are $P$ and $\{e\}.$

Likewise, $g\notin Z(P)$ means that  $C_{P}(g)\neq P$ and thus $C_{P}(g)=\{e\}.$

So:

$$p=|P|=|Z(P)|+\sum_{i=1}^r[P:C_{P}(g_i)]=1+pr$$

This is not possible.

So the assumption that $r>0$ is false.

---

Of course, it's easy to prove:

> **Theorem:** If $P$ is group with $|P|=p$ prime then $P$ is cyclic.

**Proof:** If $g\in P\setminus\{e\}$ then $o(g)\neq 1$ and $o(g)\mid |P|=p$ so $o(g)=p.$ But that means that $P=\{e,g,\dots,g^{p-1}\},$ thus $P$ is cyclic (and hence abelian.)

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helpful to start with your correct statement $P = Z(G) = C_P(g)$ for all elements of $G$.

There are therefore no $g_i$ because the $g_i$ are non-central. The class equation is then trivially true.

Comment: That is a good point. The last equality cannot hold as $g_is$ are extracted from non central elements